# onOptionsItemSelected of Fragments in FragmentStatePagerAdapter holds previous this reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have fragment (in FragmentStatePagerAdapter) which has global variable, and in onOptionsItemSelected I refer this value. It works fine for the first time, when I go back and come to the same page and update this global variable and now if I refer the values in onOptionsItemSelected it holds the previous values and not the current one.
I tried to print the "this" reference in onOptionsItemSelected, it is referring to the first reference.  Whereas the values in other methods refers to the updated value.

Edit 1 : Adding code snippet

```
   public class CustomizeFieldFragment extends BaseFragment implements CustomizeFieldListAdapter.IOnSelectCustomizeField {

private MenuItem mMenuItem;
private List<String> mSelectedFieldsId;
private boolean mShowDoneMenu;

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.customize_field_done, menu);
    mMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_done);
    mMenuItem.setVisible(false);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_done:
            updateSelectedFields();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSelect(List<String> selectedFieldsId) {
   if(!selectedFieldsId.isEmpty()){
        mSelectedFieldsId = new ArrayList<>(selectedFieldsId);
        mShowDoneMenu = true;
    }
}

private void updateSelectedFields() {

    String[] selectionArgs = mSelectedFieldsId.toArray(new String[mSelectedFieldsId.size()]);
    Uri uri = Contract.DefectFieldEntry.buildDefectFieldUri(baseUrl, domainName, projectName);
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Contract.DefectFieldEntry.COLUMN_IS_FIELD_SELECTED, true);
 //  mContext.getContentResolver().update(uri, cv, null, selectionArgs);
}
}
```

The issue is with "mSelectedFieldsId" variable. When I refer this in onOptionsItemSelected it refers to old values that was stored and in other methods it refers to the actual value.

Edit 2 : Adapter code snippet

```
public class CustomizeFieldListAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomizeFieldListAdapter.CustomizeFieldListViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = CustomizeFieldListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private Cursor mCursor;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItems;
private IOnSelectCustomizeField onSelectCustomizeField;
private List<String> mSelectedItemsId;

public CustomizeFieldListAdapter(IOnSelectCustomizeField iOnSelectCustomizeField){
    onSelectCustomizeField = iOnSelectCustomizeField;
    mSelectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
    mSelectedItemsId = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class CustomizeFieldListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView tvFieldName;
    ImageView selectionIcon;

    public CustomizeFieldListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvFieldName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customize_field_name);
        selectionIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.selection_icon);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int adapterPos = getAdapterPosition();
        toggleSelection(adapterPos);
    }
}

@Override
public CustomizeFieldListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_customize_field,
            parent, false);
    return new CustomizeFieldListViewHolder(rootView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CustomizeFieldListViewHolder holder, int position) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    holder.tvFieldName.setText(mCursor.getString(1));
    if(mSelectedItems.get(position, false))
        holder.selectionIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.select);
    else
        holder.selectionIcon.setImageResource(R.mipmap.selection_icon);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursor == null ? 0 : mCursor.getCount();
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor){
    mCursor = cursor;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void toggleSelection(int position){
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    if(mSelectedItems.get(position, false)){
        mSelectedItems.delete(position);
        mSelectedItemsId.remove(mCursor.getString(0));
    }
    else{
        mSelectedItems.put(position, true);
        mSelectedItemsId.add(mCursor.getString(0));
    }
    onSelectCustomizeField.onSelect(mSelectedItemsId);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

public interface IOnSelectCustomizeField {
    void onSelect(List<String> selectedItemsId);
}
```

}

Comment: Add the code snippet.!

Comment: If you post a snippet of the code where you update the variable, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you pass it from your adapter to the `Fragment`?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably passing a reference to your `Fragment` and changing the reference trying to update it (with a `=`).

The way variables work is, your variable holds a memory address pointing to an object in the memory. If you want to change the values of it and expect the change to reflect in other references held somewhere else, using `=` will not work.

For example, if you have an `ArrayList` in your adapter and you pass it in your `Fragment`, if you replace all the values with:

```
arrayList.clear();
arrayList.add(newValue);
```

It will reflect in all the other references you've kept as variables elsewhere, but if you do it like:

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(newValue);
```

It changes the reference, this variable `arrayList` now points to a completely different memory location, which contains a completely different object. Such changes will not reflect in other references of the older object kept elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Declare that global variable as static. And use that variable wherever you want. Let me know if this works out.

Comment: Static variables are not suitable at all places. If used in the right place, serves a good purpose, if used at a wrong place, messes things up, introduces bugs hard to find/debug.

Comment: If you are clear with all your declarations, then there is no possibility of messing things up. And it is safe  and easy to debug too.

Comment: Static variables works. But I can't make everything static, I am showing snackbar as well, it works for the first time but when I go back and come it doesn't show as it is holding previous "this" reference.